# Strange Behavior of append in two dimension slice

Tags: go, slice

I am a bit new to Go Language, and trying to build a function which will subdivide a slice into a number of slices with almost equal sizes. In case the size of the main slice does not fit into the number of sub-slices, I plan to redistribute the remaining elements to the sub-slices in order.

I have built the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    stc "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    myslice := make([]int, 12)
    myslice = []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    fmt.Println("Original Slice = ", myslice)
    newdiv := subslices(myslice, 4)
    fmt.Println(newdiv)
}

func subslices(sl []int, dividnet int) [][]int {
    var res [][]int

    minsize := len(sl) / dividnet

    for i := 0; i < dividnet; i++ {
        res = append(res, sl[i*minsize:i*minsize+minsize])
    }

    for i := 0; i < dividnet; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("res[%d] = %v\n", i, res[i])
    }

     fmt.Println(res)
     if rem := len(sl) % dividnet; rem != 0 {
        fmt.Println("remaining elements = ", rem)
        for j := 0; j < rem; j++ {
            tobeadd := sl[minsize*dividnet+j]
            fmt.Println("element to be added = ", tobeadd)
            fmt.Printf("res[%d] before append = %v\n", j, res[j])
            res[j] = append(res[j], tobeadd)
            fmt.Printf("res[%d] after append = %v\n", j, res[j])
     }
     }
    return res
}
func gentwodim(x, y int) [][]int {
    res := make([][]int, x)
    for z := range res {
        res[z] = make([]int, y)
    }

    for i := 0; i < x; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < y; j++ {
            res[i][j] = i + j
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

**A Sample in Go Play**
[sample of the above code](https://play.golang.org/p/EVuKHaSGnN3)

---

The output of the code is as follows:

```
res[0] = [1 2]
res[1] = [3 4]
res[2] = [5 6]
res[3] = [7 8]
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8]]
remaining elements =  2
element to be added =  9
res[0] before append = [1 2]
res[0] after append = [1 2 9]  // up to this step the code works fine
element to be added =  10
res[1] before append = [9 4]   // I did not get why res[1] is changed by replacing 3 with 9
res[1] after append = [9 4 10]
[[1 2 9] [9 4 10] [10 6] [7 8]]
```

However, after appending the first remaining element which shown in `res[0] after append = [1 2 9]`, the 2nd sub-slice is changed as shown from `res[1] = [3 4]` to `res[1] before append = [9 4]`
I have tried to debug and understand what I have missed or coded wrong here, but could not.

I would appreciate your support.

Comment: This is because slices have an underlying array, if you slice myslice into 4 sub slices, all these slices still have the same underlying array, they are just "looking" at a different segment of the array. Appending to one of these subslices will, if there's enough space in the underlying array, update the elements in the underlying array. Here effectively bleeding over to the next subslice.

Comment: ... see here https://play.golang.org/p/L0GyulibYB6, a copy of the subslice is created before appending to the result, that way each subslice has its own underlying array.

Comment: If you're interested in the details you can go here: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Comment: @mkopriva, Thanks a lot, you nailed the issue. Appreciate your efforts correcting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the problem by distributing the "extra" values as you slice things up:

```
func subslices(sl []int, dividnet int) [][]int {
    var res [][]int
    var i int
    for len(sl) > 0 {
        i = len(sl) / (dividnet - len(res))
        res = append(res, sl[:i])
        sl = sl[i:]
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe to avoid the bleeding over to the next element, I need to have a new subslice independently.